# M2 - Configurable product stock is 10, max to order is 6

Tags: magento2, orders, stock, quantity

I have multiple configurable products on my webshop and the quantity is set to 10, but if I want to order 7 items, I get a message "The specified number is not available". And if I order 6 items, it's good...

Does someone know how that is possible?

Regards,

Comment: Can you check the respective simple product quantity which you are trying to order?

Comment: Yes, the simple product quantity is 10